# characterization of $f(x)=d(x, A)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a set. I would like to know if there is a general characterization for real-valued function $f$ on $X$ such that
$$
f(x)=d(x, A)=\inf\{d(x,y): y\in A\}
$$
for some metric $d$ and subset $A\subset X$. Clearly such a function needs to satisfy that $f(x)=0$ whenever $x\in A$. Moreover, that function needs to be continuous in the corresponding metric (since $d(.,A)$ is continuous with respect to the topology generated by $d$). But these are all necessary conditions, and I'm curious if there are known sufficient conditions for such real-valued functions. Any pointer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: sufficient conditions for what to hold?

Comment: Are you looking for a theorem of the form "Let $(X,\mathcal O)$ be a topological space and $A\subseteq X$ a nonempty set. If $f:X\to\mathbb R$ is a function, then f satisfies conditions X,Y,Z if and only if there exists metric $d$ on $X$ which produces the same topology and on which $f(x)=d(x,A)$." where "X,Y,Z" is to be filled in.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Yes exactly. Sorry I should've been clearer.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Sorry I should have been clearer: just as Stinking Bishop suggested. Here is another way to put it: it's straightforward to check that, if $f(x)=0$ iff $x\in A$, then the function $d(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|$ is a pseudo-metric and $f(x)=d(x, A)$. But of course that construction won't in general be a metric. So I'm curious when we can construct a metric such that $f(x)=d(x, A)$

Comment: Having accepted the answer below, it seems that you want a different formulation: "Let $X$ be a set and $f:X\to\mathbb R$ a function. Then, $f$ satisfies conditions X,Y,Z if and only if *there exists a subset $A\subseteq X$ and a metric $d$ on $X$ such that $f(x)=d(x,A)$*" (the provided answer says that the only condition is that $f$ is $0$ on at least one point in $X$). I would just like to point that this is a totally different statement than the one I formulated above and you seemed to also be happy with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Literally any function $f:X\to [0,\infty)$ that takes the value $0$ somewhere is of the form $d(-,A)$ for some metric $d$ and some subset $A\subseteq X$.  Indeed, given such a function, let $A=f^{-1}(\{0\})$ and fix some point $a\in A$.  Define a metric on $X$ as follows.  For all $x\in X\setminus A$, $d(x,a)=f(x)$.  For all $b\in A\setminus\{a\}$, $d(b,a)=1$.  All other values of $d$ are given by the "shortest path" possible given the values defined so far.  That is, if $x,y\in X$ are distinct and both not equal to $a$, then $d(x,y)=d(x,a)+d(y,a)$.  It is straightforward to check that this is a metric and $d(x,A)=f(x)$ for all $x\in X$.

Comment: ah brilliant! I got stuck on constructing $d$ in a way to satisfy the triangle inequality. Thanks!

Comment: It's a good general technique for constructing metrics: define a "skeleton" of values for it and then say all other values are the shortest path between the two points generated by the skeleton.